# multiprocessing targets are run in the parent process instead, sequentially

Tags: python, websocket, python-multiprocessing

I have one function `orderbook(pair)` that opens up a websocket, subscribes to a channel and listens for messages. I want to be able to subscribe to multiple channels and listen to messages in parallel. Is there any way to do this?

As of now, I am attempting the following:

```
from dev.orderbook import *
from multiprocessing import Process

def main():
    process01 = Process(target=orderbook('BTC-USD'))
    process02 = Process(target=orderbook('ETH-USD'))
    process01.start()
    process02.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, all this does is run `process01` and only when I stop the script it runs `process02`. Which is not the behavior I am looking for. Is there any way I can subscribe to both these channels at once and listen and print messages/responses concurrently? If not, then is there any way I can start one process - let it run for a specified time and then start the next process?

My websocket mirrors the following:

```
import websocket

class orderbook(object):

def __init__(self, pair):
    self.pair = pair
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                          on_message = self.on_message,
                          on_error = self.on_error,
                          on_close = self.on_close)
    ws.on_open = self.on_open
    ws.run_forever()

def on_message(self, ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(self, ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(self, ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(self, ws):
   ws.send(self.pair)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Process` constructors include actual calls to your target function. So, the function is called, in the parent process, in the course of evaluating the constructor line, and the result is passed to `Process()` as `target`.

You should rather pass the function itself, and pass its arguments separately:

```
process01 = Process(target=orderbook, args=('BTC-USD',))
```

Comment: Okay thank you! But how can I use this to run them in parallel? or is that even possible?

Comment: @walksignison _"You should rather pass the function itself, and pass its arguments separately."_ For other things, see [the `multiprocessing` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing).